# Sqlite error in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to delete some entries in my sqlite database on my iPhone app, but am getting a weird error.

Here is my code:

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &yerocDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{   
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;

    NSString *deleteSql=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from Favorites_Table where playlist_name = Studying and date = 1/1/2012"];
    const char *sqlstmt = [deleteSql UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(yerocDB, sqlstmt, -1, &compiledstatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int result = sqlite3_step(compiledstatement);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != result)

            NSAssert1(0,@"Error while creating delete statement => %s",sqlite3_errmsg(yerocDB) );
    }else{
        NSLog(@"didn't delete error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(yerocDB));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);
}
```

but then I get the error:

```
didn't delete error: no such column: Studying
```

playlist_name and date are my columns...Why is it saying the "Studying" is not a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap `Studying` in single quotes. And your date.

This:

```
delete from Favorites_Table 
where playlist_name = Studying and date = 1/1/2012
```

Should be this:

```
delete from Favorites_Table 
where playlist_name = 'Studying' and date = '2012-01-01'
```

The reason is that if you don't put it in single quotes, the parser will think it's a column name. In your first query, you were trying to delete from `Favorites_Table` where the `playlist_name` column equalled the `Studying` column. Henceforth your error, "No such column."

And once you fixed the quotes around studying, your date was going to throw an error, too. Dates use ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd) to compare. Don't use the localized mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy formats, as a rule of thumb.